# isn't karma superior than Supreme God (Para Brahman)?

Tags: philosophy, karma, brahman

Okay first I googled who is Supreme God in Hinduism and on wikipedia I found this.

> Para Brahman (not to be confused with Brahma) is supreme God of
> hinduism. Most Hindus worship one Supreme Being, though by different
> names. This is because the peoples of India with different languages
> and cultures have understood the one God in their own distinct way

You can find the above statement [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_gods#Supreme_God)

Now I always thought that Shiv Ji, Vishnu Ji and Bharma Ji are the most supreme God's but While developing a game and talking to myself I came to this that no matter what God has created "karma" and "Karma" means the activity associated with (something, anything). So it means that even God has to do something which mean god "Karma" correct?

So in my final thought I am curious to know is "KARMA" superior then "The Ultimate One"

To give a little light to my statement:
God can do anything, ok but god HAVE to do which mean he have to think or do some kind of activity or do something which is not understandable as being human (apart from 4 dimension, 6 senses) something that human mind can't think. But this thing is also considered as "KARMA" so ultimately god is also stuck with "karma"?

I am so confused, Please solve this dilemma of mine.

Comment: Short answer. No. Karma is the effects of your own jiva's actions, past and present. God is the dispenser of the effects of your karma. Your question has multiple questions in it and has been answered in prior questions.

Comment: Most of these articles are written by westerners of Kaliyuga who believe in single birth and a black box third party God living in heavens, or Hindus influenced by them or with puranic background. In true Hinduism or Sanatan, God is not separate from Karma rather itself is the Maya or the background. The purpose of Karma is to evolve from insect to enlightened being, hence every soul like animal, bird, human is doing Karma undergoing several births. Worshipping God is limited to only limited humans,but eventually Gods like trinity, Indra, Ram, Krishna are involved in Karma Yoga as Karma is God

Comment: Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh are triguna Maya and supreme only in Puranic texts, Vedas mention 33 koti gods like Indra, Agni, Vayu, Varuna, Mitra, Rudra etc., and were worshipped in ancient yugas when Puranas werenot that popular as today. God is singular nameless Brahman or Atman and the programmer behind the Maya matrix "They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuna, Agni,
and he is heavenly-winged Garutman. To what is One, sages give many a title."  -Rigveda 1.164.46